# Sequently fadein pixels of image

Tags: canvas

I'm looking for a way to randomly fadein single pixels/parts of an image one after another.

Here is a little example gif explaining what I mean.

[image: sequently fade in parts of image]

Comment: what do you have already we can work on?

Comment: I found out that the jquery UI "explode" effect or something like that could be a basis. http://blackmiaool.com/jquery-image-explode/ - Since they render the image to different parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want as the gif.

Easy to do. Create an array of tiles. just the position and width of each tile. Then randomly remove a tile from that array and fade it in. When faded in get the next tile till there are no more.

```js
// helper functions
var imageTools = (function () {
    var tools = {
        canvas : function (width, height) {  // create a blank image (canvas)
            var c = document.createElement("canvas");
            c.width = width;
            c.height = height;
            return c;
        },
        loadImage : function (url, cb) { // cb is calback. Check first argument for status
            var i = new Image();
            i.src = url;
            i.addEventListener('load', cb);
            i.addEventListener('error', cb);
            return i;
        },
    };
    return tools;
})();
var canvas = imageTools.canvas(300,150); // create default canvas
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// set up tile data
const hTiles = 8;  // horizontal and width tiles counts
const wTiles = 8;
const fadeTime = 400; // in ms 1/1000 second
var tiles=[]; // array of tiles

// adds tile to array
function addTile(x,y,w,h){
    tiles.push({
        x : x,
        y : y,
        w : w,
        h : h,
    });
}
// load image with callback function to cut up image into tiles
var img = imageTools.loadImage("https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMsn0.jpg", function(){
    // get image size
    var w = this.width;
    var h = this.height;
    // resize ccanvas to fit image
    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;
    // get tile size
    var ww = w / wTiles;
    var hh = h / hTiles;
    // add all tiles to the tile list
    for(var y = 0; y < hTiles; y += 1){
        for(var x = 0; x < wTiles; x += 1){
            // need to be careful with rounding
            addTile(
                Math.floor(x * ww),
                Math.floor(y*hh),
                Math.floor((x + 1) * ww) - Math.floor(x * ww),
                Math.floor((y + 1) * hh) - Math.floor(y * hh)
            );
        }
    }
    this.ready = true;
})

var globalTime;  // global to this 
var tile = null;  // hold currently fading tile
var allDone;

// main update function
function update(timer){
    globalTime = timer;
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;           // reset alpha
    
    // Start tiles when img is complete. Ie loaded
    if(img.ready){
        if(tile === null){ // need a tile
            if(tiles.length > 0){ // are there any tiles left
                // remove a random tile from the array of tiles.
                tile = tiles.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * tiles.length),1)[0];
                tile.startTime = globalTime; // set the start time
            }else{  // all done
                // just exit to stop
                ctx.font = "28px arial black";
                ctx.fillText("All done!",10,30);
                return;
            }
        }
        if(tile !== null){
            var f = (globalTime-tile.startTime) / fadeTime; // get normalised fade time
            if(f >= 1){ // all done with this tile. draw it and setup for the next
                ctx.drawImage(img,tile.x,tile.y,tile.w,tile.h,tile.x,tile.y,tile.w,tile.h);
                tile = null;
            }else{
                // clear background for this tile
                ctx.clearRect(tile.x,tile.y,tile.w,tile.h);
                ctx.globalAlpha = f; // Just set to the alpha
                // draw the tile
                ctx.drawImage(img,tile.x,tile.y,tile.w,tile.h,tile.x,tile.y,tile.w,tile.h);
            }
        }
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```